# aws mwaa is not creating cloud watch log streams

Tags: amazon-web-services, mwaa

It logs the below error in the Task.
This same task has no issues in the dev environment. This issue started in prod environment sometime after mid Feb 2022. Noticed it now. Nothing has changed.

```
Could not read remote logs from log_group: airflow-Prod_Airflow_V222-Task log_stream: import/Import-Project/2022-05-02T05_20_00+00_00/3.log
```

This log stream itself is missing. I checked the
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/mwaa/latest/userguide/t-cloudwatch-cloudtrail-logs.html#t-task-logs

Everything looks ok. Tasks are showing as completed successfully

Answer (score 0):

The MWAA environment's execution role may not contain a permissions policy to create log streams for task logs. You'll need to modify the execution role's policy to allow creation of log streams. See the references below.

Example policy:

```json
{
    "Effect": "Allow",
    "Action": [
        "logs:CreateLogStream",
        "logs:CreateLogGroup",
        "logs:PutLogEvents",
        "logs:GetLogEvents",
        "logs:GetLogRecord",
        "logs:GetLogGroupFields",
        "logs:GetQueryResults"
    ],
    "Resource": [
        "arn:aws:logs:{your-region}:{your-account-id}:log-group:airflow-{your-environment-name}-*"
    ]
}
```

References:

1. [I see 'Could not read remote logs from log_group: airflow-*{*environmentName}-Task log_stream:* {*DAG_ID}/*{*TASK_ID}/*{*time}/*{*n}.log.' in my task logs (AWS)](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/mwaa/latest/userguide/t-cloudwatch-cloudtrail-logs.html#t-task-fail-permission)
2. [Amazon MWAA execution role (AWS)](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/mwaa/latest/userguide/mwaa-create-role.html)

Comment: MWAA-Execution-Policy attached to the role has all the above permissions.

Comment: The documentation also mentions potential issues with `requirements.txt`. Assuming no issues there, right?

Comment: We are noticing this issue when the load is high. Looks like its an inherent bug in MWAA

Answer (score 0):

I fixed it. The logging level for Task logs was set to WARNING. So no log streams were produced. Changed it to INFO. Everything started working